# Convert C++ array of struct w/o tons of new calls?

Tags: c#, c++, static-array

C++

```
typedef struct someStruct {
   int val1, val2;
   double val3;
} someStruct;

someStruct a [1000] = { {0, 0, 0.0}, {1, 1, 1.0}, ... };
```

The only way to initialize such a table in C# I know of is to write something like

```
class SomeStruct 
{
   int val1, val2;
   double val3;

   public SomeStruct (int val1, int val2, double val3)
   {
      this.val1 = val1;
      this.val2 = val2;
      this.val3 = val3;
   }
}

SomeStruct[] a = new SomeStruct [1000] 
{ 
   new SomeStruct (0, 0, 0.0), 
   new SomeStruct (1, 1, 1.0), 
   ... 
};
```

Is there a way to have a be a (reference to) an array of values of type class SomeClass instead to pointers to those?

Edit:

The point is that I want to avoid having to call new for each struct in the array. So what I want is an array containg 1000 structs and not 1000 pointers to (1000) structs. The reason I am asking is that the way C# handles this appears insanely inefficent to me, involving a lot of memory and memory management overhead (over e.g. C++).

I had tried something like

```
struct SomeStruct {
   int a, b;
   double c;
   }

SomeStruct[] a = new SomeStruct [1000] { {0,0,0.0}, {1,1,1.0}, ... };
```

But that wasn't possible. So though I know that structs are value types, I concluded that this is only true when passing them as parameters to function, and I had to use new, like this (using structs here):

```
struct SomeStruct {
   int a, b;
   double c;
   SomeStruct (int a, int b, double c) {
      this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c;
      }
   }

SomeStruct[] a = new SomeStruct [1000] { 
   new SomeStruct {0,0,0.0}, 
   new SomeStruct {1,1,1.0}, 
   ... 
   };
```

Comment: The C++ code sample is actually C style.  In C++, there's no need for the `typedef`.  If this is an example of the code you're working with, then it's either C (which is probably easier to port) or very bad C++ (probably harder).

Comment: The third parameter of the `SomeStruct` constructor needs to be `double`, not `int`.

Comment: David, I know I don't need the typedef, but I find it more readable this way.
Ben, you are right, but it is only an example I wrote in a minute w/o checking it to much, and it is good enough because it makes the principle clear. 
I would like to ask both of you not to post irrelevant replies in the future that have nothing really to do with the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the struct keyword in C#. C# structs are value types- an array of structs is contiguously stored structs, identical to a C++ standard array.

Comment: I tried that, but still couldn't initialize the array with struct values, like e.g. SomeStruct[] a = new SomeStruct [1000] { {0,0,0.0}, {1,1,1.0} ...};

Comment: @karx - did you read my solution? It's the only way you're going to avoid the new calls within the initialization syntax.

Comment: Yes I did, and thank you for your proposition. I was rather looking for avoiding having to allocate each struct separately though.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but this will work (if you change the type to `struct` instead of `class`)

```
SomeStruct[] a = new SomeStruct [1000];
a[0].val1 = 0;
a[0].val2 = 1;
a[0].val3 = 2.0;
...
a[999].val1 = 0;
a[999].val2 = 1;
a[999].val3 = 2.0;
```

**Edit:**

If this is a global field, declare `a` as `static readonly`.

Comment: This is assignment, not initialization.  It also doesn't work for immutable value types, which are recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a new collection for SomeStruct (derived from `IEnumerable<>`) Each item you use in the initialization syntax gets converted to a call to `.Add(...)`, so provided your collection class has a method called Add (doesn't need to inherit from any other interface for this), with matching arguments, you can use the same C++ syntax.

eg.

```
public class SomeStructCollection : IEnumerable<SomeStruct> {
    private readonly SomeStruct[] someStructs = new SomeStruct[1000];
    private int currentIndex;

    public void Add(int val1, int val2, double val3) {
        someStructs[currentIndex++] = new SomeStruct(val1, val2, val3);
    }

    public SomeStruct this[int index] {
        get { return someStructs[index];
    }

    //Implement IEnumerable<> interface.
}
```

Calling code can then wrap values in some blocks

```
SomeStructCollection coll = new SomeStructCollection {
    {0, 0, 0.0}, {1, 1, 1.0}, { ... },
};
```